# Add text to the circle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to write the information about the quarter circle on the right side.
[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]
I want it aligned and I want to do it as practically as possible.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=50mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A},
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B},
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){C},
\draw [black, very thick] (A)--(0:4) arc[radius=4, start angle=0, end angle= 90]--(C)--(A)--cycle;
\node at (5,4) {$x+y+z=1$};
\node at (5,3) {$text$};
\node at (5,2) {$2x^2=3$};
\node at (5.6,1) {$4x+5x-4=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks:
You don't need to load `TikZ` because `tkz-euclide` uses `TikZ`.
You don't need to use `;` unless you use code from `TikZ`.
If you want to place labels you can use `tkzText` but also a `node` is possible.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,0/4/C}
  \tkzDrawSector(A,B)(C)
  \tkzText[align=left, font={\baselineskip=4ex},
           text width=3cm](6,3)
           {$x+y+z=1$\\$text$\\$2x^2=3$\\$4x+5x-4=0$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove `text width=3cm` as it is not necessary.

Comment: @Unknown. yes and no You are right in this case but if you want to put a frame or if you need to limit the width it's a possibility.

Comment: The line breaks are set manually in the question and also by you, so the additional setting of a text width will maybe lead to confusion with longer lines (automatic "line break", since text width is reached). Also, if you replace `text width=3cm` with `draw` you get a perfect frame around the text (independent of the text width).

Comment: Regardless, your solution is still the best (in my opinion), since `TikZ` and `tkz-euclide` commands are not mixed and also the correct setting of the `arc` values is omitted.

Answer (score 6):

This is very short with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, array}
    \usepackage{pstricks}

    \begin{document}

    \psset{unit=3cm, linejoin=1}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,1)
    \pswedge{1}{0}{90}
    \rput[tl](1,1){$\begin{array}{l}x + y + z = 1 \\ \text{text}\\ 2x^2 = 3 \\ 4x + 5y - 4 = 0\end{array}$}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A},
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B},
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){C},
\draw [black, very thick] (A)--(0:4) arc[radius=4, start angle=0, end angle= 90]--(C)--(A)--cycle;
\node[align=left, font={\baselineskip=4ex}] at (6,2.5) {$x+y+z=1$\\$text$\\$2x^2=3$\\$4x+5x-4=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quarter circle with formulas]

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities. In both cases, the placement is done from point *P* located at 1/4 from the start of your quarter-circle arc. Because of the `above right` key I use (from the `positioning` Ti*k*Z library), the point that is explicitly placed relatively to *P* is the `south west` anchor of the rectangle node containing the text.

Note that you should remove the commas after your `\tkzDefPoint` lines: each of these commas causes the warning `Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!` to be printed on the standard output and log file of TeX!

## Using `align=left` for a multiline node

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){C}

\draw[black, very thick]
  (A) -- (0:4)
  arc[radius=4, start angle=0, end angle=90] coordinate[pos=0.25] (P)
  -- (C) -- cycle;
\node[align=left, above right=0em and 1em of P]
  {%
   $x+y+z=1$\\[0.5ex]
   \textit{some text}\\[0.5ex]
   $2x^2=3$\\[0.5ex]
   $4x+5x-4=0$%
  };
\fill[blue] (P) circle[radius=3pt] node[below left=2pt of P] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Variant for the line spacing: hpekristiansen's `font={\baselineskip=4ex}` [idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646572/73317) (however, I'd suggest `font={\setlength{\baselineskip}{4ex}}` or `font={\baselineskip=4ex\relax}` instead).

## Using a `tabular` inside a single-line node

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){C}

\draw [black, very thick] (A) -- (0:4)
  arc[radius=4, start angle=0, end angle=90] coordinate[pos=0.25] (P)
  -- (C) -- cycle;
\node[above right=0em and 1em of P]
  {%
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% set row spacing
   \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
     $x+y+z=1$\\
     \textit{some text}\\
     $2x^2=3$\\
     $4x+5x-4=0$
   \end{tabular}%
  };
\fill[blue] (P) circle[radius=3pt] node[below left=2pt of P] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]